# AddDays function on attribute

Tags: attributes, microstrategy

I am new to Microstrategy and I having one doubt. I am trying to display amount sales of sales corresponding to DayDt(date type attribute ) and amount of sales for (DayDt-365 days).

I tried to use AddDays function but it seems directly I can't apply it on this attribute .It support only metrics.So I created a metric(DayDt Metric) based on the sum(DayDt).

But the value coming in the DayDt Metric Column is integer .how can I convert this value into date.

Also : I would be pretty grateful if anyone can tell any other procedure to achieve my purpose

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you need is a Transformation.

Create a new transformation based on the DayDt attribute and as Expression use DayDt Id - 365 days (I'm not in front of MicroStrategy now, but you should be able to use formulas here, so AddDays or a similar one will help you).

Save the transformation with a meaningful name like "Last Year"

Make a copy of your orignal metric, but in the trasformation section add the Last Year traansformatio you just created.

Save it as "Amount of Sales (LY)" or the name that you prefer.